# Installing Ubuntu16.04 on Lenovo G50-80, facing error

Tags: 16.04

Trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo G50-80 laptop(Free DOS 1.1.26a version)

I want to override the FreeDOS and I have USB bootable.

but facing errors attached image

[image]

Comment: Please use an offline or [online](http://imgur.com/) image editor to crop the image to the area of interest only, as it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are facing bad image or unsuccessful transfer to usb. I would recomend to download again and create new flash drive. Use. `unetbootin` or in windows `rufus` to create the usb stick. I would recomend downloading torrent file instead of regular download. If you are using `ubuntu` for the usb creation, `startup disk creator` will do the trick.

Comment: I have used PowerISO to made a bootable disk and it worked. thanls